# How to use barcode without EAN13?? in odoo

Tags: templates, odoo, barcode, odoo-10, qweb

We want to print internal Product Barcodes because we do not need EAN Numbers for our Products. But it's not working when i put it into the Products "Internal Reference" Field. (example code: BX06WO01)

When i enter this number into the Product/"Internal Reference" Field and "Print Product Label" our Barcode Scanner can not read the printed code, generated from Open ERP In odoo Feature

Is it possible to export and scan a code like BX06WO01(Both Letters and Numeric values) ????

Thanks in Advance.......

Answer (score 4):

The label is based on a Odoo QWeb report, which can be found under Settings/Technical/User Interface/Views. You need to have the debug mode activated to see that menu.

There just search for `report_simple_label`. You can exchange `EAN13` with for example `Code128`. [Accepted types](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/65f5fc6bf8442fc7004d0fc8e006184359f0fe4e/addons/report/controllers/main.py#L62) are:

```
Accepted types: 'Codabar', 'Code11', 'Code128', 'EAN13', 'EAN8', 'Extended39',
    'Extended93', 'FIM', 'I2of5', 'MSI', 'POSTNET', 'QR', 'Standard39', 'Standard93',
    'UPCA', 'USPS_4State'
```